# How should I clean this pan?

Tags: pan, stainless-steel, burnt

I've been using this pan for a while, and have somehow scorched the bottom of the pan. Can someone tell me how I should clean it? Thanks!

[image: burnt pan]

Comment: Does the inside of the pan look similar? I am usually not concerned by any discolorations on the *outside* of my pans.

Comment: No, the inside is completely clean.

Comment: It's called usage @EdwardRusli, totally normal and nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 4):

The discoloration is from overheating the pan, not from stains. The actual metal has changed color through accidental [tempering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tempering_(metallurgy)), so you won't be able to clean it off other than by grinding the metal down or re-tempering it (neither of which is a good idea).

The color won't significantly affect the performance of the pan. Just ignore it.

Answer (score 1):

For me it looks ok.

Most people will leave the bottom of the pan as-is or do light cleaning with dish soap and a "plastic" scrubbing pad.

Other people will use a product like Bar Keepers Friend to do a more in depth scrubbing.